# C++ Inheritance: Calling the virtual function of a base class using an instance of a derived class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I am trying to get a grasp about **Virtual** functions and inheritance in C++. In the example code below, I have two classes AreaCube (base class) and SideAreaRatio (derived class). I am trying to call the virtual function "**area**" in base class from another function "**ratio**" which is inside the derived class. And I am trying to achieve this, using an instance of the base class. But for some reason which I am not familiar of, I am seeing weird answer being generated. Please enlighten me here of what is going on!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class AreaCube {
public:
    int side;
    AreaCube() {};

    AreaCube(int s) {
        side = s;
    }
    virtual ~AreaCube() {};

    virtual int area() {
        cout<< "calling.. " << endl;
        int area = side*side*side;
        return area;
    }
};

class SideAreaRatio:public AreaCube {
public:
    SideAreaRatio(int s) {
        side = s;
    };

    ~SideAreaRatio() {};

    float ratio() {
        AreaCube a;
        int area = a.area();
        cout<< area << endl;
        return (side/area);
    }
};

int main() {
    AreaCube* ac = new AreaCube(2);
    cout<< ac->area() << endl;
    SideAreaRatio* sar = new SideAreaRatio(4);
    cout<< sar->ratio() << endl;
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
calling.. 
8
calling.. 
8
0.3333
```

**Generated Output:**

```
calling.. 
8
calling.. 
-1265467392
0
```

Comment: Using the debugger, you should have found the problem in a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because you're not actually constructing the `AreaCube` object with any value, so when it calculates the area it gives you garbage (because the `side` variable has no value, as demonstrated by calling the default constructor).

I *think* that what you wanted to do is:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class AreaCube {
public:
    int side;
    AreaCube() {};

    AreaCube(int s) {
        side = s;
    }
    virtual ~AreaCube() {};

    virtual int area() {
        cout<< "calling.. " << endl;
        int area = side*side*side;
        return area;
    }
};

class SideAreaRatio:public AreaCube {
public:
    SideAreaRatio(int s) {
        side = s;
    };

    ~SideAreaRatio() {};

    float ratio() {
        int area = area();
        cout<< area << endl;
        return (side/area);
    }
};

int main() {
    AreaCube* ac = new AreaCube(2);
    cout<< ac->area() << endl;
    SideAreaRatio* sar = new SideAreaRatio(4);
    cout<< sar->ratio() << endl;
}
```

You don't need to instantiate a `AreaCube` inside the derived class, because everything you need is already there. Just call the `area()` method.

When you inherit from a base class, you keep all member variables and member functions, so you don't need to instance anything but your derived class. So, in this case, SideAreaRatio has both a side variable and an area() method

It's worth mentioning that you're not really using the `virtual` method for anything, though.

Comment: You're welcome. When you inherit from a base class, you keep all member variables and member functions, so you don't need to instance anything but your derived class. So, in this case, `SideAreaRatio` has both a `side` variable and an `area()` method.

Answer (score 2):

The new instance `a` of `AreaCube` you're creating using the default constructor, which doesn't set the value of `side` on instance `a`. This memory is not guaranteed to hold any particular value and when you call `a.area()`, the result is going to be undefined.

There's a simple fix: replace `AreaCube a;` with `AreaCube a(side);` and see if you get the right behavior. Alternatively, you can avoid instantiating a new instance of `AreaCube` altogether and simply invoke the base class method directly: `int area = AreaCube::area()`. Note that you don't need to pass `side` here since the base class method operates on the current object's (`this`) state.

Also, another problem that's going to prevent this from working: when you divide two `int` variables, it will truncate the result to `int`. You need to get this to perform floating-point division: replace `return (side/area);` with `return (1.0f * size / area);` and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

In your `SideAreaRatio` class you create a new object of type `AreaCube` using the default constructor (`AreaCube()`) when `ratio` is invoked which does not initialise the `side` member field of the class. Next you proceed to perform computations on the still undefined value of `side`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `float ratio()` to

```
float ratio() {
    int area = area();
    cout<< area << endl;
    return (side/area);
}
```

Because `SideAreaRatio` **is-a** `AreaCube`, the area function can be used directly.

Answer (score 0):

here

```
float ratio() {
    AreaCube a;
    int area = a.area();
    cout<< area << endl;
    return (side/area);
}
```

you create an object a which is initiated with the default constructor. However, your default constructor for AreaCube does nothing. So if you really want to create a new object, use

```
AreaCube a(side);
```

instead.

Or you can call

```
area()
```

directly without create a new object of AreaCube, i.e.

```
 float ratio() {

    return (side/area());
}
```

The reason why you call

```
area()
```

directly is that this method is defined in the base class. In this situation, even it is not defined as virtual, you could still use it. You can have a try and see the result is the same.

Basically your code is not a right implementation of virtual function.